# Having trouble running COUNT in my INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sqlite

I'm having a little trouble getting my head around this statement. The idea is it's meant to initialize a table with a single row of values for each player in the database, but I can't figure out from a browser full of search tabs what I'm doing wrong. All I know is apparently my syntax is rubbish.

```
INSERT INTO tblKebabs 
  (TransactionID, PlayerID, Amount, Description, Timestamp) 
SELECT 
  (COUNT(tblPlayers.PlayerID)) AS TransactionID,
  tblPlayers.PlayerID AS PlayerID,0 as Amount,
  "Initializer" as Description,"now" AS Timestamp) 
FROM tblPlayers 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID > 0;
```

Comment: Can you post the entire statement. I need to see how you're grouping.

Comment: Someone edited the post and ruined the code i typed. it is NOT the original post, information is missing, thank you karel.
I will have to re-edit the question so the code is intact and not obliterated

-edit, thank you forpas for repairing it <3

Comment: That's better. TBH, @forpas answer below is the best - I'm not sure why you'd put a COUNT into an ID field - it wouldn't be unique to start with. If it's genuinely the count you need for some reason, then you need to GROUP BY the fields so that you actually get a COUNT value out.

Comment: i put a count into an ID field because i am noobcore and was unaware how to define an integer feild as a primary key at first. It seemed like a good idea at the time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `TransactionID` column to be `AUTOINCREMENT` you have to define it in the `CREATE` statement. 
If you already have defined it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` it is already `AUTOINCREMENT` and you don't need to change something. 
If you have nothing of the above then you have to recreate the table with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` for this column because SQLite does not allow such changes with `ALTER`. 
 Now you can omit this column from your statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblKebabs 
  (PlayerID, Amount, Description, Timestamp) 
SELECT 
  PlayerID,
  0 as Amount,
  'Initializer',
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
FROM tblPlayers 
WHERE PlayerID > 0;
```

You don't need aliases in the `SELECT` statement. 
Also I used `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but if it's just about the count, try this

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblPlayers.PlayerID) AS TransactionID
```